# Rails 5. How to submit from the form_tag to custom action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, submit, action

I'm a real newbie at Ruby and Rails, and I've been looking for the solution for two days. I need to submit data from form_tag to action '*create*' in my controller to add new entries to database, but looks like I'm doing something terribly wrong, because absolutely nothing happens, and it seems that form_tag doesn't even redirect to needed action.
Here's the page code:

```
<h1>Todos</h1>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
      <h2><%= project.title %></h2>
      <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
      <ul style="list-style-type:disc">
        <li><%= todo.text %></li>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_tag({controller: "mega", action: "create"}, method: "get", remote: true) do %>
  <h2>New todo</h2>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag 'text' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag 'title',  options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, 'id', 'title') %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'CANCEL' %>
    <%= link_to 'OK', "", :onclick => "$('#form_id').submit()" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And the controller:

```
class MegaController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @todos = Todo.all
  end

  def update
  end

  def create
    @newTodo = Todo.create(text: params[:text])
    @newProject = Project.find_by(title: params[:title])
    @newProject.todos << @todo
    @newTodo.save
  end
end
```

My routes file. I seriously don't know how it works:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'mega/index'

  root 'mega#index'

  get 'mega/update'

  post 'mega/create'

  resources :todos
  resources :projects

end
```

Comment: Seems like you should probably be getting a routing error in your console (where you're running your server). Forms don't usually 'get'. They usually 'post'. Anyway, you should probably add the text from your console to your question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I don't seem to get any errors. Is there a way to find an error log?

Comment: If what you are looking to do is create a action that creates several resources at once there is a rails way to do it. Its an advanced topic thats not really suited for a noob though. I would recommend you take a good tutorial and figure out the rails conventions first instead.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to create new 'todo' using form_tag. 'Todo' belongs to a 'project' and consists of a text. But when I hit link to submit. page briefly refreshes, and nothing happens, not even a new 'todo' appears in the database

Comment: Do you run your server from the console? That's where you should see you log.

Answer (score 2):

You create resources with a POST request. **Never GET.**

GET requests should be idempotent - they should not update or alter resources on the server. One very important reason is that they are stored in the browser's history, so pressing the back button will cause unintended consequences for the user.

In Rails flavor MVC instead of tacking the action name on the path of the route you use the HTTP verb to create routes to the correct action:

```
GET   /things    things#index
POST  /things    things#create
```

I'm not going to attempt to salvage your code (it's deeply flawed) and instead show you how you would solve this the rails way as it is much simpler:

```
<%= form_for(Todo.new) do |f| %>
  <h2>New todo</h2>
  <%= f.text_field :text %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:project_id,  @projects, :id, :title, prompt: true) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This would submit to `todos#create` - if you want to route it to an unconventional action you can use the `url` option:

```
<%= form_for(Todo.new, url: polymorphic_path(controller: 'foo', action: 'bar')) do |f| %>
```

It's best to learn the rules before you break them.

Comment: Instead of spending two days barking up the wrong tree you might want to start with a tutorial like [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/). You can't really figure it out on your own as writing good apps and being productive is about learning how Rails apps are built.